# Message is not coming into channel even my endpoint is declared as Bridge

Tags: spring-integration

In my application i have service activator which is taking message in input-channel, doing some process in activator method and putting back the processed message into **output-channel** to saving in db using mongo-adapter.

I have declare *output-channel* like `<int-channel id="outputchannel"/>`

In my junit test to test the message in **outputchannel** i used  as below.

`<bridge input-channel="outputchannel" output-channel="testInputChannel">`

The testInputChannel is declared as *QueueChannel*

Still the message is going mongo-adapter input-channel="outputchannel".

Do i need to definitely declare outputchannel as `pub-sub` channel. Otherwise it won't come to `testInputChannel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two subscribers, the messages will be sent to the mongo adapter and bridge in round-robin fashion.

To test, you could have your test replace the channel with a pub/sub.

Or `stop()` the mongo adapter; which is generally better for test cases.

You can use `auto-startup="${should.start}"` and use a property to not start the adapter in test cases, but start it for production.

The mongo adapter won't be subscribed to the channel until it is `start()` ed.

Or, if your test only sends one message, make sure the bridge is the first subscriber to the channel.